virtual encryption vs non virtual?
quick question, i couple of months ago i was talking to someone over discord and they told me that veracrypt isn't very good because it was a "virtual" encryption program and that non virtual encryption programs are some how better
they didn't provide me any examples and i lost touch with them so i couldn't interrogate them about it, so i wanted to ask you guys here
is there a difference between virtual and non virtual encryption programs? if so what is the difference? is veracrypt some how not as good as other encryption programs because it's "virtual"?
thank you

At best there is a difference between software and hardware encryption. Of course, if you're talking of encrypting a partition, part of the encryption program has to run in software as hardware generally doesn't deal with partitions or file systems.

They don’t know what they’re talking about, “virtual encryption” isn’t a term used in cryptography and has no obvious meaning here.

“Virtual encryption” doesn't mean anything, so they were probably not criticizing the encryption in Veracrypt, but some other aspect of the software.
It's possible that they meant a virtual disk (i.e. a big file containing all the encrypted data) as opposed to a physical disk. But if so they were misinformed: Veracrypt supports both. In any case, a virtual disk isn't objectively bad. It's very slightly slower than going directly for a physical disk, but it's more convenient if you want to move it around, back it up or enlarge it. There is no difference in terms of security.
It's also possible that they were talking about the way Veracrypt hooks into the operating system. Veracrypt has to appear as some kind of virtual disk driver to the operating system. Whether the operating system interface is called “virtual something” depends on the operating system. In any case it's unimportant.
Whatever it is, ”someone over Discord“ is pretty low on the level of trust that I'd put in someone knowing what they're talking about.
”Someone on Stack Exchange“ should be a bit higher, so here's my advice. Veracrypt (in its older name Truecrypt) became popular when major operating systems didn't support encrypted storage well or at all. Nowadays they do. I recommend using your operating system's encrypted storage: it's likely easier to set up, faster, and just as secure. However, if you want to access the same encrypted storage from multiple operating system, Veracrypt is a good choice.
